# Unittest a transactional method with REQUIRES_NEW and always force rollback

Tags: spring, jpa, junit, spring-transactions

I want to test a service-method that inserts data into a table by calling a DAO in a loop. The service-method is annotated with

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

The unit-test calls the service-method and is annotated with

```
@Transactional
```

Now I would like to tell the transaction that it always should do a rollback at the end. I don't want to clean up the db manually after the testruns.

@Rollback and EntityManager.getTransaction().setRollbackOnly() does'nt work. I think the reason is that the annotation and setRollbackOnly() are only applied on the Transaction that is created by the test-method and not on the transaction that is created by the service-method.

Does anyone know how to solve that?

Comment: Mock the DAO, inject it by hand into a newly constructed service, and test the method. You don't need a Spring context or transactions to unit test services.

Comment: This is what I'm doing right now. But anymway, I still would like to know if it is possible to set the transaction to rollbackonly.

Comment: If you were doing that, you wouldn't need to rollback anything, since you wouldn't have transactions. `new Service(mockDao).callMethod()` doesn't start a transaction, so there's nothing to rollback.

Comment: Please try to understand the question in a scientific way. I dont need a solution to go on with my work. I just want to know if that is possible or not, and - if it is posiible how I can do that.

Comment: Possible to do what? rollback a non-existing transaction? No, that's not possible.

Comment: Why is it non existing? I thought @Transactional would create one? Because of Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW? This would create a new one which is not visible from junit-context?

Comment: Because the annotation is only used if a spring context has been loaded that understands these annotations, and if the object you're calling is indeed a spring bean obtained from the spring context. If you use `new Service()` to create your service instance, Spring isn't aware of this object and has no way to intercept the method call and start a transaction. An annotation doesn't do anything by itself.

Comment: Im using this to initialize the Spring-context: @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestContextConfiguration.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)

Comment: The Rollback works If I use another PropagationType (REQUIRES) for the Transactions.

Comment: *This is what I'm doing right now.*: So, you're not doing at all what I suggest. What I suggest it to avoid loading a Spring context completely, and to instanciate the service by yourself, using new.

Comment: That was an reply to "Spring isn't aware of this object and has no way to intercept the method call and start a transaction". I just wanted to show that this is indeed possible if you run your tests under Spring-context. Which is what I am doing in n tests where I test DAOs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to easily rollback a REQUIRES_NEW transaction. SpringTest starts a transaction and it can rollback the transaction that it started. But not the transactions started inside.

So you either may fall back to REQUIRED or write your tests to work fine even if they commit. If you choose the latter, you can achieve test isolation via [randomization](http://qala.io/blog/randomized-testing.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can probably create a controllable mock implementation of `org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager` delegating to the real one with only single difference that it would optionally mark a new transaction as read-only. Something like that if using java-based context configuration:

```
...
public class DaoTest {
...
@Autowired
Dao _dao;
@Autowired
MockPlatformTransactionManager _transactionManager;
...
@Test
@Transactional
public void testSomeAction() throws Exception
{
    try (AutoCloseable ignored = _transactionManager.withRollBack())
    {
        _dao.someAction();
    }
}
...
interface MockPlatformTransactionManager extends PlatformTransactionManager
{
    AutoCloseable withRollBack();
}
...
// Somewhere in the @Configuration class
@Bean
MockPlatformTransactionManager transactionManager()
{
    // an instance of real TM is adapted to become a MockPlatformTransactionManager 
    return new MockPlatformTransactionManager()
    {
        private final PlatformTransactionManager _delegate = 
            // TODO: same transaction manager as before
            new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
        private boolean shouldRollBack = false;

        @Override
        public TransactionStatus getTransaction(final TransactionDefinition definition)
            throws TransactionException
        {
            final TransactionStatus transaction = _delegate.getTransaction(definition);
            if (shouldRollBack)
                transaction.setRollbackOnly();
            return transaction;
        }

        @Override
        public void commit(final TransactionStatus status) throws TransactionException
        {
            _delegate.commit(status);
        }

        @Override
        public void rollback(final TransactionStatus status) throws TransactionException
        {
            _delegate.rollback(status);
        }

        @Override
        public AutoCloseable withRollBack()
        {
            shouldRollBack = true;
            return new AutoCloseable()
            {
                @Override
                public void close() throws Exception
                {
                    shouldRollBack = false;
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a PlatformTransactionManager implementation that permits to set the UserTransaction (like org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager) you can instantiate an UserTransaction implementation which commit method does a rollback.

```
import com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp;

@Bean
public UserTransaction myUserTransaction() {
    final UserTransactionImp userTransactionImp = new UserTransactionImp() {            

        @Override
        public void commit() throws javax.transaction.RollbackException, javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException,
                javax.transaction.HeuristicRollbackException, javax.transaction.SystemException, java.lang.IllegalStateException,
                java.lang.SecurityException {
            rollback();
        }
    };

    return userTransactionImp;
}
```

And then, in your PlatformTransactionManager bean:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
        @Qualifier("myUserTransaction") UserTransaction myUserTransaction,
        @Qualifier("myTransactionManager") TransactionManager myTransactionManager
) {

    final JtaTransactionManager jtaTm = new JtaTransactionManager();

    jtaTm.setTransactionManager(myTransactionManager);
    jtaTm.setUserTransaction(myUserTransaction);

    return jtaTm;
}
```

I've also made my dao does not make any flush.